# Implemeting a basic FTP client in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, client

I want to write a FTP-Client in Java with a restriction: No advanced libraries (e.g. .ftp, .url etc.) allowed.

How do I implement a method to print the current directory, change directory and download a simple .txt-file?

Comment: How about using `java.net.Socket`?

Comment: .net.socket is allowed.

Comment: How about doing some research. You said "I want to write", but it seems more like "I want you to write for me".

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by reading up the RFC governing the FTP protocol. With that you can get an idea on how the FTP protocol works, how it sends commands, expected responses etc.

You can find a link here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959

Aside from that you can have a look at this GitHub repository. In there you'll find a simple FTP client that I wrote back when I was in uni. The `FtpConnection` class implements most of the commands you'll need to do your job.

Have a look at it and how these are used.

https://github.com/Kortex/Simple-FTP-Client